# My css ::after apply only on the last element

Tags: html, css, gradient

I've wanted to add a border bottom gradient to my div, after looking on the net I found a solution which is :

```
.element {
  height: 55px;
  max-width: 400px;
  background-color: #454A4D;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.element:after {
   content: "";
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #343738 0%, #e07051 100%);
   display: block;
   height: 4px;
   width: 400px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

"element" is the class of my div,

What I get is exactly the style I want, but it's only applied for the last div with the class  `.element` ! which give this :

[image]

Any clue ?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: Most likely because the after is set to `position:absolute` and `bottom: 0` so they're all appearing stacked up on top of each other at the bottom.

Comment: can we see the html?

Comment: can we see css of `.element` ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask]. This question is about JavaScript/HTML/CSS, so you should consider using a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the menu items (element 1, element 2 and element 3) are not positioned. They are `static`. The element containing them has a `position` (`absolute`, `fixed` or `relative`) which causes the `after`'s to take that element as reference to place them selfs.

Setting position relative on element would fix your problem:

```
.element {
    position: relative;
}
.element:after {
    content: "";
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #343738 0%, #e07051 100%);
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set position property to relative to your .element selector.